# Cómo hacer mi Android App compatible con Tablets

Tags: android

He investigado sobre cómo hago que mi Android App sea compatible con Tablets para que aquellos usuarios que tengan Tablets puedan descargar mi App desde Google Play.

Muchas opiniones, métodos diferentes, etc.. aún me he quedado con la duda.

He agregado en mi `AndroidManifest` lo siguiente:

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />
```

En mi `build.gradle` tengo:

```
minSdkVersion 18
targetSdkVersion 27
```

1. Enserio debo agregar minSdkVersion al `AndroidManifest`?
2. Realmente todo esto sería suficiente para poder soportar tablets? o hay algo más por hacer?

Comment: Hola, segun me acuerdo se crea un xml del activity con el mismo nombre y alli diseñabas la vista para tablet, creo que te puedes guiar de esto https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820353/Create-an-app-for-Phone-and-Tablet

Comment: En los resources, debes crear su vista para el formato Tablet y llamarlo igual que el que usas para los otros formatos(para que no se confunda la app al usar el setContentView).

Answer (score 2):

Tu app ya es compatible con tablets si es que NO pones alguna restricción, dejando el manifest tal cual se crea permite que tu app sea descargable por smartphones y tables, ahora si te refieres al diseño para tablets necesitas incluir 2 layouts; 1 para smartphones y otro para tablets.

En tu directorio `layout` incluye 2 layout, el normal y uno para tablets:

**Layout**

- activity_main
- activity_main_tablet

Dentro del directorio `res`, si NO la tienes crea una carpeta llamada **values-sw600dp** y dentro crea un XML llamado "layout" para indicar cuál layout debe tomar para dispositivos igual o mayores a 600dp (Tablets).

**values-sw600dp**

- layout

código de "layout" XML dentro de `values-sw600dp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="layout" name="activity_main">@layout/activity_main_tablet</item>
</resources>
```

En este XML lo que estás indicando es que: en los dispositivos igual o mayores a 600dp de ancho (tablets) **el sistema reemplazará** el layout de nombre "**activity_main**" **por** "**activity_main_tablet**" del directorio layout

## =======================

Problablemente también quieras usar `dimens` para establecer medidas en márgenes, paddings, etc. igual en la carpeta `values` se encuentra un archivo `dimens` con tus medidas normales (para teléfonos) y en la carpeta `values-sw600dp` tendrías que crear un XML llamado también "`dimens`" y ahí establecer las medidas para tablets.

Te dejo un poco de documentación al respecto:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support